# angular service not manipulating values as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I have an angular service to handle my promises, but I am not sure how to manipulate the values on $scope from within the service.  I understand what I am doing is wrong, but don't understand what I need to do to be right.

In my service:

```
.service('resolvePromiseService', function(){
    var publicInterface = {
        resolvePromise: resolvePromise
    }

function resolvePromise(promise, resultObject, callBackFunction, spinner){
    spinner ++;
    promise.then(function(result){
        resultObject = result;
        if(callBackFunction){
            callBackFunction();
        }
    });
    promise['catch'(function(error){
        //generic error handling
    });
    promise['finally'(function(){
        spinner--;
    });
}
```

and in my controller which calls the service

```
var getInfoPromise = dataAccessService.getInfoByLocationId(locationId).$promise;
resolvePromiseService.resolvePromise(getInfoPromise, $scope.locationInfo, $scope.setUpLocation, $scope.loadingSpinner);
```

Inside the resolvePromise function, I am seeing the values come in as expected and being updated as expected, but I think I am misunderstanding the way $scope is passed around.  I believe I am replacing the angular objects with vanilla javascript objects.

Comment: JavaScript has a `return` statement. For more information, see [MDN JavaScript Reference -- return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return). Use it to avoid all the convolutions with callbacks.

Comment: @georgeawg incredibly helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option would be for you to pass in your scope object or rethink how you are handling promises.

The reason this is happening is to do with modifying references.

In your example

```
$scope.loadingSpinner = 5; // ref1 - val 5
function resolvePromise(promise, resultObject, callBackFunction, spinner){
  // when we enter the function both $scope.loadingSpinner and spinner are both 
  // referencing the same variable
  spinner; // ref1 - val5
  // after we increment spinner the local reference is no longer pointing 
  // at the reference
  spinner; // ref2 - val6
  // therefore we are not actually updating the $scope.loadingSpinner 
  //reference just the local spinner one
}
```

I have included a snippet to demonstrate this point - you need to keep in mind that you are reassigning the reference which is not what you intend to do in this instance.

```js
angular
  .module('Test',[])
  .service('IncrementService', incrementService)
  .controller('MyController', myController)

function incrementService() {
  this.increment = function(valToInc) {
    valToInc++;
    console.log(valToInc);
  }
  
  this.incrementScopeField = function($scope, field) {
    $scope[field]++;
    console.log($scope[field]);
  }
}

myController.$inject = ['$scope', 'IncrementService'];

function myController($scope, IncrementService) {
  $scope.number = 5;
  $scope.inc = function() {
    IncrementService.increment($scope.number);
  }
  $scope.inc2 = function() {
    IncrementService.incrementScopeField($scope, 'number');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='Test' ng-controller='MyController'>
  <button ng-click='inc()'>increment value</button><button ng-click='inc2()'>increment scope</button>
  <br/>{{ number }}
</div>
```

Comment: is it bad practice to pass `$scope` into a service

Comment: It is not ideal - it would be better to handle the result of the promise inside your controller. In this instance resolve the promise with your incremented value then assign `$scope.loadingSpinner` in the closure

Comment: the issue with this is that I have multiple `$scope` variables that need to be changed within the promise resolution.  i'm missing a piece of greater architecture I believe

Comment: this is the right example -- plus addresses the issue of not passing `$scope` into the service